# How to correctly set the SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER from a connection?

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I'm using Peewee and obtain my connection from an URL like this:

```
from playhouse.db_url import connect

db = connect('sqlite:///C:/some/file.db')
connection = db.connection()
connection.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON')
# How can I set the SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER here?
connection.execute('?????????????????')
```

How can I correctly increase the `SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER`? I am stuck in an older 2.x SQLite version and can't upgrade unfortunately ... corporate policies. I am aware that the latest versions of SQLite have increased the default limit beyond 999.

Comment: You have to compile a customized version of sqlite with the larger value defined. So you might as well upgrade at the same time. *2.X*?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation here: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_variable_number

You will need to recompile Sqlite to raise the limits.